# Pattern substitution - Python

Tags: python, pattern-matching

I have a expression filter string for a commodity such as

`$city=="Paris" and $country=="France" and $price<100 or $units > 95`.

I want to replace the `$` preceded string with a function call to read the value of field from context(ctx)

The expected output:

```
read(ctx, city)=="Paris" and read(ctx, country)=="France" and read(ctx, price)< 100 or read(ctx, units) > 95
```

What would be the cleaner way of doing this in python?

Comment: FWIW, `read(ctx, price) < 100 or read(ctx, units) > 95` would capture all values.

Comment: I don't really understand the context. If you were reading from a CSV file, for example, you'd read a row and expand the row into variables that would be testable -- so that would be no problem. If you were selecting from a database, you would similarly have columns named and the selection criteria would be in SQL -- so that would be okay. If you had a search technique that returned class objects, you'd just use dot notation. If your search returned a dictionary, use dictionary lookup. But you appear to have an API that returns a function -- never seen that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is similar to named group matching. However I have used `replace` to remove the `$` after doing the substitution

`In [1]: re.sub(r'(?P<field>\$[\w]+)', 'read(ctx, "\g<field>")', '$city=="Paris" and $country=="France" and $price<100 or $units > 95').replace("$", '')`

`Out[1]: 'read(ctx, "city")=="Paris" and read(ctx, "country")=="France" and read(ctx, "price")<100 or read(ctx, "units") > 95'`